# Rails4: How to display the data one time only in each roop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to display the data as followings;

```
Day1
09:00 Math
11:00 Science
Room classA (3rd floor)

Day2
10:00 English
13:00 Music
Room classB (1st floor)
```

sample articles table

```
school_id day start_time title
1         1   09:00      Math
1         2   10:00      English
1         1   11:00      Science
2         1   12:00      Physics
1         2   13:00      Music
```

sample rooms table

```
school_id day name    detail
1         1   classA  3rd floor
1         2   classB  1st floor
2         1   classC  2nd floor
```

I think I should realize SQL in Rails as below to display rooms data.

`SELECT name, detail FROM rooms WHERE articles.school_id = rooms.school_id AND articles.day = rooms.day`

It would be appreciated if you could give me the best way in Rails although I tried some code.

View code

```
<div class="row">
  <% @articles.each do |a| %>

      <%= a.start_time %>&nbsp;<%= a.title %><br>
      <!-- I can't display rooms.name and rooms.detail in the X Day last line-->

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller code

```
def show
  @articles = Article.where(school_id: (params[:id])).order(day: :asc)
```

Model code

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles


class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school


class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    #(nothing)
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150999999999) do

  create_table "rooms", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "detail"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "start_time"
    t.string   "end_time"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "contents"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "schools", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: I would consider storing the last iteration's relevant data (i.e. `day`) and whenever the last iteration's data and the current iteration's data don't match, print out the `Day n` line (updating the stored value, of course)... this assumes the data is organized according to day values.

Comment: What type of data format is your "time" column?

Comment: Is a room always the same for a complete day? I would assume an "article" (why not name it a course or lesson?) could also have it's own room?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Rich Peck. The format of "time" column is `hh:mm` (i.e. 09:20, 16:45).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @nathanvda. Yes, a room is always the same for a complete day. An "article" (means course or lesson, I should rename it as you advised) doesn't have it's own room.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by fetching the data from database, and assigning it to some local variable

```
articles = Article.where(school_id: (params[:id]))
```

Then you can group records by day:

```
articles_by_day = articles.group_by(&:day)
```

result of this operation would be hash with days as the key and arrays of articles as the values.

Then we need to actually sort Articles by start_time within the day:

```
articles_by_day.values.each{|x| x.sort_by!(&:start_time)}
```

And then get Articles data sorted by day:

```
@articles = articles_by_day.keys.sort.map{|k| [k, articles_by_day[k]]}
```

Resulting value in @articles will be an array of 2 value tuples: day and articles within the day. Like [[1, [#{struct Article day=1, name="Science",...},...]], ...]

Then you can use it in templates in the following way:

```
<% @articles.each do |(day, day_articles)| %>
   Day <%= day %><br>
   <% day_articles.each do |a| %>
     <%= a.start_time %>&nbsp;<%= a.title %><br>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the SQL [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) functionality; meaning you can [`.group`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) your `Articles` by `day`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :schools do 
   resources :rooms, controller: :articles #-> url.com/schools/:school_id/rooms/:id
end

#app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @school = School.find params[:school_id]
      @room   = @school.rooms.find params[:id]
      @articles = room.articles.group(:day).order(day: :asc)
   end
end
```

This will give you an array of days, containing hashes of articles:

```
#app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<% @articles.each do |i,articles| %>
   <%= i %>
   <% articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= article.start_time %><%= article.title %>
   <% end %>
   <%= "Room #{article.room_name} #{article.room_detail}" %>
<% end %>
```

(this won't work unless you associate `articles` and `rooms`):

---

I think there's a problem in your code; specifically that you're allocating `rooms` without linking them to either `school` or `article`:

```
#app/models/room.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | school_id | name | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :school
   has_many :class_rooms
   has_many :articles, through: :class_rooms
end

#app/models/class_room.rb
class ClassRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Divides Article + Room for each school and day
  #columns id | day | room_id | article_id | start_time | end_time | detail | created_at | updated_at
  #NB room_id should associate to each school.
  #Detail moved to ClassRoom (denotes which class will be in room)
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :room
end

#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | category | title | contents | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :class_rooms
   has_many :rooms, through: :class_rooms
   has_many :schools, through: :class_rooms
end


#app/models/school.rb
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | address | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :rooms
   has_many :class_rooms
   has_many :articles, through: :class_rooms
end
```

Such example data may include:

```
#Schools
id name      address
1  School A  1 Avenue
2  School B  2 Avenue
3  School C  3 Avenue

#Articles
id category title    contents
1  x        English  English Literature
2  x        Math     Basic Arithmetic
3  x        Science  Science

#Rooms
id school_id name
1  1         1st floor
2  2         2nd floor
3  1         3rd floor

#ClassRooms
id  day  room_id  article_id  start_time  end_time  detail
1   1    1        1           12:00       13:00     ClassB
1   2    1        1           12:00       13:00     ClassA
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
@school   = School.find params[:id]
@rooms    = @school.rooms
@articles = @rooms.find(params[:room_id]).articles.group(:day)
```

To do this, you'll have to include the `day` and some extra params through the `has_many :through` association.

It will provide you with all relevant data:

```
<% articles.each do |day, articles| %>
   <%= "Day #{day}" %>
   <% articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= "#{article.start_time} #{article.title}" %>
   <% end %>
   <%= "Room #{article.room.name} (#{article.room.detail})" %>
<% end %>
```